# Create a nested checkbox in streamlit

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit

I need to create nested checkbox as below. It will expand once it is click and can have multiple checkbox checked.
[image]

```
from pathlib import Path
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_gsheets import GSheetsConnection
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import streamlit_authenticator as stauth

if action == "Add New Company":
    st.markdown("Enter the details of the new company below.")
    with st.form(key="my_form"):
        materialsupplier = st.checkbox('Material Supplier', key='one')
      
        servicesupplier = st.checkbox('Service Supplier', key='two')
        if servicesupplier:
            st.checkbox('Automation')
            st.checkbox('Engineering')
            st.checkbox('Logistics')
            st.checkbox('Management')
            st.checkbox('Consulting')
            st.checkbox('Trading')
        steeluser = st.checkbox('Steel User', key='three')
        if steeluser:
            st.checkbox('Roll Formers')
            st.checkbox('Coil Service Centres')
            st.checkbox('Fabricators')
        submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label="Submit Company Details")
```

However, the outcome is not desirable. I need

1. The checkbox in second level such as Automation, Engineering until trading to indent to inner right instead as all display the same left margin.
2. the second level of checkbox will only show after I hit the submit button. I need it to expand before hit the submit button.

Kindly advice how shall I proceed with it. I am with Streamlit version 1.28.2

[image]